# Only save user session on certain requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express-session

Im using [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) and [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to keep track of a user's session. I have the following code to set the session:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'scamp',
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        ttl: 60 * 30 // half hour
    })
}));
```

The problem with this is that a session is created for every request sent to the server. For example, Im using Amazon Web Services to host my app and every 10 seconds that sends a request to my server to make sure its still up (its called a health check). The health check request is a GET request to mydomain/health. But with the code I have, this creates a new session which is stored in a sessions collection in my remote Mongo Db. So the database grows massive very quickly.

Some background: my app allows users to upload files, and then interact with each file. I only want the session to keep track of the CURRENT file a user is interacting with (in my session I keep the current file id, file path, current file parameters selected etc). So basically, I only want to set the session for certain requests to my API, not all.

So I thought I would re-write my code:

```
var setsession = function (req, res, next){

    session({
        secret: 'scamp',
        store: new MongoStore({
            mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
            ttl: 60 * 30 // half hour
        })
    })

    next();
};

app.use(setsession);
```

I was then planning to do a check within `setSession()` to see what the request endpoint was, and set the session if the request was one of the oens I want a session for. However, after changing my code above, this immediately breaks my app. Below I have:

```
app.get('/api/canvas', function(req, res) {

    sess = req.session;

    var callback = function() {

        graphController.constructGraph();
    };

    console.log('req.session is ', req.session);

    var graphController = new GraphController(req, res, sess, callback);
});
```

Now, after moving `session()` out of `app.use` and into its own method, req.session is `undefined` and my app breaks. Any idea why this happening?

Also, is this a good approach to stop a session being stored on every request to the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `saveUninitialized` option to prevent the session to be saved if it does not contain any data.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'scamp',
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        ttl: 60 * 30 // half hour
    }),
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

> Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified. Choosing false is useful for implementing login sessions, **reducing server storage usage**, or complying with laws that require permission before setting a cookie. Choosing false will also help with race conditions where a client makes multiple parallel requests without a session.
>
> The default value is true, but using the default has been deprecated, as the default will change in the future. Please research into this setting and choose what is appropriate to your use-case.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#saveuninitialized